# Screen goes black after some seconds

Tags: windows, laptop, display

I have an HP Compaq Presario CQ61-310SD Notebook. And when I start my computer on the highest brightness, my screen would go dark after a few seconds. I can hear that moment that it goes dark.

I've formatted/reinstalled drivers and stuff. But still I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

The thing is when I start the notebook with a lower brightness, it will work for 10 minutes or so but then just the same problem..

I can use an external monitor / vga cable, and that works..

Comment: What can you hear when the screen goes dark? Does the screen come back on or does it remain dark?

Comment: It remains dark. And i hear something bzzzzz when it's going to dark out.

Comment: One of my friends came to me with this exact same issue and the exact same laptop a couple days ago. I wasn't able to help him. I think there is a bad batch of back lights in this models screen. The issue does not seem to originate from software at all.

Comment: Do you have the `Power Saver` option selected on the Laptop's `Power Options`?

Comment: Boot into the BIOS and see if the screen still goes dark after X amount of time. You may be able to eliminate the OS causing this issue.

Comment: If you don't start the computer with the highest settings, can I assume it operates as desired?

Comment: Nop, none of that all work. I've took it apart, and pulled the invertor out, and back in. Now it works again like it should ..